# How to use Brotli compression in Spring Boot?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, brotli

I have a production deployed Spring Boot service behind envoy and currently it has an API that uses gzip compression and serves JSON response. Recently came across Brotli and I'm trying to figure out how to use this compression in the application. Any references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Ideally you'd put your application behind a reverse proxy that takes care of the compression (and usually TLS termination as well).

i.e. put it behind a web server like Nginx, Apache or another alternative.
Then you'll be able to set the desired compression settings that best answer your needs.

See here the Brotli module for Nginx in this case and how to set it up:
https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli