# Spring Boot 3 embedded Tomcat Brotli compression instead of GZIP

Tags: angular, brotli, spring-boot-3, embedded-tomcat

We have a Spring Boot 3 (3.1.1) application with an Angular frontend. By setting the following properties, the static files (e.g. main.js) are delivered compressed with gzip:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=4096
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/font-sfnt,application/font-woff,application/font-woff2
```

Is it possible to set `brotli` as the default compression algorithm for on-the-fly compression?

By creating compressed files (`gzip` and `brotli`) during compilation, the embedded tomcat delivers the `brotli`-compressed file. As we do not want to create those compressed files during compilation, we are looking for a way to ensure that the embedded tomcat in the Spring Boot 3 application compresses the files on the fly. But we haven't found a way yet to do so using `brotli`.

We also do not want to put our application behind a proxy as suggested in [How to use Brotli compression in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830609/how-to-use-brotli-compression-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I doubt that Tomcat supports this. Given the fact that tomcat hardcoded sets `responseHeaders.setValue("Content-Encoding").setString("gzip");` when encoding is enabled. So Tomcat doesn't support this, as you don't want a proxy your only solution is to write your own `BrotliEncodingFilter` which does this.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid that Tomcat does not support this. We'll maybe write our own filter or just stick with gzip.

Thanks for the response.